I don't get the use of his

Without his even knowing it, the answer was already there for him sitting fully formed in his head.
The New York Trilogy
Paul Auster

Why does the sentence use his? I would have used him.

In writing and formal speech , traditional grammar requires using a possessive pronoun (e.g. 'his') before a gerund or gerund phrase (like 'even knowing'), A gerund is the verb form that functions as a noun. This rule is broken frequently, with many writers using the objective case (e.g. 'him') rather than the possessive case.

Does this answer your question? Is there any difference between these sentences Also A gerund or a participle? and others.

The reasoning is clearer to see in a different example. Consider a scenario where a young man who's deeply in love laments to his beloved,

I hate you leaving.

The object of the verb hate, is not you but leaving: it's not his beloved that gets hated but a leaving. Which leaving in particular? The beloved's leaving. And notice that in that last phrase I just wrote, The beloved's leaving, you'll find a possessive.
Another way to see the same thing is that in that example, leaving is a noun. If we substituted a synonym like departure and retained you, we'd end up with an obviously ungrammatical sentence (*I hate you departure). So we'd have to use the possessive your.

M+W compares the use of the possessive pronoun and the object case before gerund-participles.

Mabel doesn't approve of you/your wearing her beret.


Grammarians over the centuries have been divided on which version of this sentence is better.
... the advice you're likely to come across these days favors the possessive ...
But you'll also see examples aplenty in otherwise unimpeachable writing of sentences like "Mabel doesn't approve of you wearing her beret." This has been true for centuries: good writers use both constructions, and often in close proximity.

Ngram shows the trend.    The possessive pronoun is still more common, but the gap between that and the object case is narrowing.
I believe the object case is likely to be even more common in oral conversations and informal writing.
The OP’s example,

Without his even knowing it ...

hence is the correct form to use in examinations and formal writing but unnecessary in informal use.
